# Moving the places of the 1's

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, minimum, subtraction

I have 2 matrices. Matrix A is already defined.

```
  Matrix A = [10 7 8 4 1 6;
              2 6 4 3 5 1;
              7 3 2 2 8 7;
              6 2 3 10 11 4;
              1 5 1 2 4 5]

 Matrix B =  [1 1 1 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 1;
              0 0 0 1 1 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Here each row has to have at least one '1'. This is our main target, so if there is a row with no 1's in it, we will have to move a '1' from another row.

How will we move the 1?

1) Check which rows that are all zeros. In this example, row 2 and 5.

2) We will subtract these 2 rows with all other rows that contain 1's in Matrix A.        Which means that row 2 and row 5 in matrix A will be subtracted by all the other rows.

3) After the subtraction, we will check the change between each 2 subtracted rows, in the places of the 1's. 
For example:

subtracting row 2 (all zeros) from row 1 will give us this `[8 1 4]` and

subtracting row 5 (all zeros) from row 1 will give us this `[9 2 7]`.

subtracting row 2 (all zeros) from row 3 will give us this `[6]` and

subtracting row 5 (all zeros) from row 3 will give us this `[2]`

subtracting row 2 (all zeros) from row 4 will give us this `[7 6]` and

subtracting row 5 (all zeros) from row 4 will give us this `[8 7]`..

4) In the places of the 1's we will check the change between the rows and see the minimum change. The column that satisfied the minimum change, we will put the 1 in its place and remove it from the old place.

For example here: 
For row 2, we will see where was the minimum change. Here the minimum change for row 2 was 1, which is in row 1. So we will remove the 1 of this column, and move it to the same column in row 2.

```
                         [1 0 1 0 0 0;
                          0 1 0 0 0 0;
                          0 0 0 0 0 1;
                          0 0 0 1 1 0;
                          0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

subtracting row 5 (all zeros) from row 1 will give us this `[8 4]`.

subtracting row 5 (all zeros) from row 3 will give us this `[2]`

subtracting row 5 (all zeros) from row 4 will give us this `[8 7]`..
The same for row 5, check the minimum change. Here it is 2 but it is the only one in the array which is in row 3. So for this case we want to add a condition, that we don't do the subtraction method unless there is two 1's or more in the row. so we will move to another minimum change which is here the 4 which is the change from row 1 so will remove the 1 in row 1 and put it in row 5

so here the output will be =

```
                         [1 0 0 0 0 0;
                          0 1 0 0 0 0;
                          0 0 0 0 0 1;
                          0 0 0 1 1 0;
                          0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

and now the condition is satisfied, each row has at least one 1.

This is what i wrote in the code

```
%search for zero-rows in matrix B
minim = max(A) % Set the minimum value as an initial solution
zeroRows = find(sum(B,2)==0);
nonZeroRows = find(sum(B,2)~=0);
x = [];
y = [];

 for zi = zeroRows'
  for nZi = nonZeroRows'


       %gives row vector of A with elements, where corresponding  B elements are 1
       %this row nZi in B is not zero
       nonZeroRow  = A(nZi,B(nZi,:) ==1);
       nonZeroFull  = A(nZi,:)

       %gives row vector of A with elements, where corresponding  B elements are 1
       %this row zi in B is zero
       zeroRow  =A(zi, B(nZi,:) == 1);
       zeroFull  = A(zi,:)

       %calculate the distance
       disp(strcat('row ',num2str(nZi), ' - row ', num2str(zi)))
      change =  abs(nonZeroRow - zeroRow)
      changeFull = nonZeroFull - zeroFull
   x = [x change]
   y = [y;changeFull]
  Minimumchange = min(x)
   if(Minimumchange < minim)
       minim = Minimumchange

   intersection =  intersect(y,minim)
for i = 1 : length(intersection)
    [w Index_intersection] = find(y == intersection(i))

    B(zi,Index_intersection) = 0
    B(nZi,Index_intersection) = 1
end 
   end 
   end    
end
```

This is the code so far but its not giving the right output

Ask me if the question is still not clear.!

Comment: How does subtracting `[0 0 0 0 0 0]` from `[10 7 8 4 1 6]` yield `[8 1 4]`? This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: From Matrix A  [2 6 4 3 5 1] from [10 7 8 4 1 6] will gives us [8 1 4] in the places of the 1's and here the 1's are in the 1st 3 columns

Comment: It looks like you have very clearly detailed how to perform the operations. Are you having trouble writing the code? If so, you should include what you have written so far in the question.

Comment: I added some code lines that i wrote. But i am stuck in the way of coding. As soon as i update anything in the code, i will post it and i will really appreciate it if i got some help. As this will help me move to another part.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment due to the lack of my reputation I'll try it this way...
this would be your steps 1,2 and 3:

```
A = [10 7 8 4 1 6;
    2 6 4 3 5 1;
    7 3 2 2 8 7;
    6 2 3 10 11 4;
    1 5 1 2 4 5];

B =  [1 1 1 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 1;
    0 0 0 1 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0];

%search for zero-rows in matrix B
zeroRows = find(sum(B,2)==0);
nonZeroRows = find(sum(B,2)~=0);

for nZi = nonZeroRows'
   for zi = zeroRows'

       %gives row vector of A with elements, where corresponding  B elements are 1
       %this row nZi in B is not zero
       nonZeroRow  = A(nZi,B(nZi,:) ==1);

       %gives row vector of A with elements, where corresponding  B elements are 1
       %this row zi in B is zero
       zeroRow  =A(zi, B(nZi,:) == 1);

       %calculate the distance
       disp(strcat('row ',num2str(nZi), ' - row ', num2str(zi)))
       abs(nonZeroRow - zeroRow)
   end    
end
```

However I don't understand what you mean in step 4. Could you formulated your step 4 shorter and more precisely? Or give some examples with intermediate steps?

Comment: this gives exaclty those vectors you described in step 3. I checked it myself

Comment: Okay let me explain more. Now we want to move the 1 with the minimum change between the rows. So for row 2 we will check where does the minimum change happen, as you can see the changes where [8 1 4], [6] and [7,6] we will see which number is the minimum among them. It is the 1 as you can see. So we will move the 1 of matrix B that is in the column that gave us this small change and put it in row 2. Do you get it? Tell me if you still have questions

Comment: did you check my comment? @viet